# Loop to export data to tab-delimited file adds extra column

Tags: c#, export, text-files, csv

I have a program that exports the contents of a gridview to a tab-delimited text file. It works fine, but the resulting file has an extra column. I'm sure the problem must be how I'm constructing my rows (adding an extra tab to the last entry), but I can't figure out what to do about it. Any help is appreciated.

My code to export:

```
public void ExportGrid(GridView gv, string gvName)
{

//  Build the text file data
string txt = string.Empty;

txt += "<table id='tblCTSWContracts' border='1'>";

//  Add the header row for text file
txt += "<tr>";
foreach (TableCell cell in gv.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
    txt += "<th>";        
    txt += cell.Text + "\t";
    txt += "</th>";
}
txt += "</tr>";

//  Add header line
txt += "\r\n";

foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
    //  Add the Data rows            
    txt += "<tr>";
    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        txt += "<td>";
        txt += cell.Text + "\t";
        txt += "</td>";
    }
    txt += "</tr>";
    //  Add new line    
    txt += "\r\n";    
}

txt += "<table>";

//  Export the file
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + gvName + ".html");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
Response.Output.Write(txt);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry, I said extra row, but it is adding an extra column.

Answer (score 0):

I brute-forced it. kept track of columns and added the "/t" for all lines except the last one. Not elegant, but if it works, it works.